# Error accessing object item in React Native

Tags: javascript, json, react-native

I'm trying to access an object that is returned from my json / api.

When I get to the object the return is normal, however when I get to some object item the simulator displays an error.

My code that works, returning the complete object:

```
render() {
    const boleto = this.props.boletodetalhe.data.unico;
    console.tron.log(boleto);
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>

      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

On my console I have the following return.
[image]

If I change my code, placing an item of my object to be displayed on the console generates an error.

```
console.tron.log(boleto.nome);
```

Adding the item name it generates an error in my simulator.
[image]

This is my call.

```
import api from 'services/api';
import { call, put } from 'redux-saga/effects';
import global from 'services/global';

import { Creators as boletodetalheActions } from 'store/ducks/boletodetalhe';

export function* BoletodetalheRequest(action) {
  console.tron.log('PAYLOAD');
  console.tron.log(action);
  try {
    const response = yield call(api.get, `Boleto/GeraBoletoFinal?code=${global.key}&IdBoleto=${action.payload.boleto.id}&IdSacado=${action.payload.sacado.id}`);
    if (!response.data.erro) {
      yield put(boletodetalheActions.boletodetalheSuccess(response.data));
    } else {
      yield put(boletodetalheActions.boletodetalheError(response.data.mensagem));
    }
  } catch (err) {
    yield put(boletodetalheActions.boletodetalheError('Chamada inexistente'));
  }
}
```

And this is my reducer.

```
export const Types = {
  ADD_REQUEST: 'boletodetalhe/ADD_REQUEST',
  ADD_SUCCESS: 'boletodetalhe/ADD_SUCCESS',
  ADD_FAILURE: 'boletodetalhe/ADD_FAILURE',
};

const initialState = {
  data: [],
  loading: false,
  errorOnAdd: null,
  carregou: false,
};

export default function boletodetalhe(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case Types.ADD_REQUEST:
      return { ...state, loading: true };
    case Types.ADD_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        data: action.payload.Data,
        loading: false,
        errorOnAdd: null,
        carregou: true,
        modal: true,
      };
    case Types.ADD_FAILURE:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: false,
        errorOnAdd: action.payload.message,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export const Creators = {
  boletodetalheRequest: (user, boleto, sacado) => ({
    type: Types.ADD_REQUEST,
    payload: {
      user,
      boleto,
      sacado,
    },
  }),

  boletodetalheSuccess: Data => ({
    type: Types.ADD_SUCCESS,
    payload: {
      Data,
    },
  }),

  boletodetalheError: message => ({
    type: Types.ADD_FAILURE,
    payload: {
      message,
    },
  }),

};
```

Comment: Include the code for how you are calling the API and handing the returned request.

Answer (score 0):

Please initialize data as an object rather an array. Change this

```
const initialState = {
   data: {}, // Change this line, from [] -> {}
   loading: false,
   errorOnAdd: null,
   carregou: false,
};
```